# Find first strictly "latest" date in a array "before" a given date

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with three items edited:(the sorting of the array is not by date, any date can be at any order):

```
[
  {
    "amount": 10,
    "date": "2020-04-21",
  },
  {
    "amount": 75,
    "date": "2020-04-22",
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "date": "2020-04-30",
  }
]
```

I'm trying to make a (vue) function that for each date, it returns the "previous" date amount

```
previousAmount(givendate){
            var sum = []; // I need to use this for other purposes
            console.log(givendate) // print the current date the function is working on
            for (var i = 0; i < this.vuedataarray.length; i++) {
                if (givendate > this.vuedataarray[i].date) {
                    console.log(this.vuedataarray[i].date) // should only print the first date found before givendate, is printing ALL the dates before givendate
                    sum.push(this.vuedataarray[i].amount)
                };
            }
            console.log(sum)
}
```

If the `givendate` is `2020-04-30`, `sum` is printing as `[75, 10]`, and not just `[75]`, as `75` is the amount of `2020-04-22`, the first date before `2020-04-30`, what I would like to achieve.

I've found an [article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/first-strictly-smaller-element-in-a-sorted-array-in-java/) that describes exactly what I want to achieve, but using a simple array of only integers without keys, and other languages.

Comment: Is the array always guaranteed to be sorted by date?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't understand your question, could you explain it?

Comment: The array in your question has the entries in date order (the earliest is first, the one in the middle is second, and the latest is third). Is that always true? Or is the later day sometimes earlier in the array than an earlier date?

Comment: thanks @T.J.Crowder , no, the array will not always be sorted this way, the later day can be at various positions, as this array simulates user items (which can be created anytime) ordered by id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're pushing to your `sum` *every* time you find a date in the array that's earlier than the one you were given, rather than only when you find the *latest* date in the array before the one you were given.

You've said the array isn't always in date order, so that means you always have to loop through the entire array. You'll need to keep track of the date and amount that you think *might* be the one you need, but then update them if you find a more recent date earlier than the given date:

```
function previousAmount(givendate) {
    const sum = [];
    let prevAmount, prevDate;
    for (const {amount, date} of vuedataarray) {
        if (date < givendate && (!prevDate || date > prevDate)) {
            prevAmount = amount;
            prevDate = date;
        }
    }
    if (prevDate) { // Checks we found one at all
        sum.push(prevAmount);
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
// Note: I've changed the array order so that the one we want is at
// the end, out of order
const vuedataarray = [
  {
    "amount": 10,
    "date": "2020-04-21",
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "date": "2020-04-30",
  },
  {
    "amount": 75,
    "date": "2020-04-22",
  }
];

function previousAmount(givendate) {
    const sum = [];
    let prevAmount, prevDate;
    for (const {amount, date} of vuedataarray) {
        if (date < givendate && (!prevDate || date > prevDate)) {
            prevAmount = amount;
            prevDate = date;
        }
    }
    if (prevDate) { // Checks we found one at all
        sum.push(prevAmount);
    }
    console.log(sum);
}

previousAmount("2020-04-30"); // [75]
```

---

**If** the array were always sorted in date order, there are two approaches.  One is to start at the end and loop backward:

```
function previousAmount(givendate) {
    const sum = [];
    for (let i = vuedataarray.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        const {amount, date} = vuedataarray[i];
        if (date < givendate) {
            sum.push(amount);
            break; // Stop looping
        }
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const vuedataarray = [
  {
    "amount": 10,
    "date": "2020-04-21",
  },
  {
    "amount": 75,
    "date": "2020-04-22",
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "date": "2020-04-30",
  }
];

function previousAmount(givendate) {
    const sum = [];
    for (let i = vuedataarray.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        const {amount, date} = vuedataarray[i];
        if (date < givendate) {
            sum.push(amount);
            break; // Stop looping
        }
    }
    console.log(sum);
}

previousAmount("2020-04-30"); // [75]
```

Another one is to remember the last number you saw, then stop looping when you see a date equal to or later than the one you were given:

```
function previousAmount(givendate) {
    const sum = [];
    let prevAmount = null;
    for (const {amount, date} of vuedataarray) {
        if (date >= givendate) {
            // Stop looping
            break;
        }
        prevAmount = amount;
    }
    if (prevAmount !== null) {
        sum.push(prevAmount);
    }
    console.log(sum);
}
```

Live Example:

```js
const vuedataarray = [
  {
    "amount": 10,
    "date": "2020-04-21",
  },
  {
    "amount": 75,
    "date": "2020-04-22",
  },
  {
    "amount": 100,
    "date": "2020-04-30",
  }
];

function previousAmount(givendate) {
    const sum = [];
    let prevAmount = null;
    for (const {amount, date} of vuedataarray) {
        if (date >= givendate) {
            // Stop looping
            break;
        }
        prevAmount = amount;
    }
    if (prevAmount !== null) {
        sum.push(prevAmount);
    }
    console.log(sum);
}

previousAmount("2020-04-30"); // [75]
```

Comment: brilliant, the first one worked well, thanks for the answer and all the explanation!